# Create 3D graph from 2 variable function that uses linear algebra to solve system of equations

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

So, i'm doing this project for my electromagnetism class and I need to plot a 3D graph in python. I normally plot 3d graphs using meshgrids, but the function used to calculate the value uses linear algebra, and since meshgrids are matrices, it seems to be causing some problems. Does anyone know how to work around this problem?

This is the code I made:

```
#Vamos importar os módulos que precisamos
from math import *
from cmath import *
from numpy import linalg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show
from numpy import exp,arange

k=0.1   
R1=0.4*3.5
R2=R1
L1=83e-6
L2=L1
C1=0.47e-6
C2=C1
Rc=10
M=k*sqrt(L1*L2)
V1=5

# the function that I'm going to plot
def CalcularTransformador(K,w):
    Vp=2/pi*5
    Rc=10
    
    XL1=1j*w*L1
    XL2=1j*w*L2
    XC1=(-1j)/(w*C1)
    XC2=(-1j)/(w*C2)
    
    M=K*sqrt(L1*L2)
    XM=1j*w*M
    
    Z=np.array([[R1+XL1+XC1, -XM],[-XM, XL2+R2+(Rc*XC2)/(Rc+XC2)]])
    V=np.array([Vp,0])

    i=np.dot(linalg.inv(Z),V)
    
    V2=i[1]*(XL2+R2+(Rc*XC2)/(Rc+XC2))
    return i[0], i[1],V2
 
CalcularTransformador(0.1,150000)
w_angular=np.linspace(150000,260000,1000)
k=np.linspace(0,1,1000)

K,W = meshgrid(k, w_angular)
#print(K,W)
Valores = CalcularTransformador(K, W)

im = imshow(Valores,cmap=cm.RdBu)
show()
```

Comment: You need to explain your function in English. See [ask]. Debug by yourself at first. Anyway, you are creating a 4D tensor in ```Z = np.array([[R1+XL1+XC1, -XM], ...)``` of shape (2, 2, 1000, 1000). Did you mean it? Then, calling ```numpy.linalg.inv()``` on it is a nonsense.

Comment: @relent95 that's exactly it, by using the meshgrid as input this happens, not by mistake, just because it can't work this way (as you explained yourself). I think I need another way to plot this graph, not using meshgrid (not sure if this even exists). By the way, the function is basically solving for the currents in the primary and secondary coils for a transformer using linear algebra. "CalcularTransformador" is portuguese to Calculate Transformer .

Comment: I mean 'in English' to be 'not in Python'. Your ```CalcularTransformador()``` returns a tuple. Anyway what about looping through k and w_angular if the performance is not a concern.